# Docker: Jupyter hides path in web interface when mounting a volume

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, persistence, docker-volume

I am trying to set up Jupyter Notebook inside a docker container. I am using the popular image `jupyter/datascience-notebook`. I used the following command to test out the image:

```
docker run -d --rm --name jupyter -p XXXX:XXXX jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

This created a new container with a running Jupyter application. Jupyters web interface puts me to `/home/jovyan` and I can see the folder `work`. This is where i want to create my notebooks.

In order to save data, i want to mount a volume to the path `/home/jovyan/work`. I tried the following two commands:

```
docker run -d --name jupyter -p XXXX:XXXX -v /volume1/homes/user/myPath:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/datascience-notebook

docker run -d --name jupyter -p XXXX:XXXX --mount type=bind,source=/volume1/homes/user/myPath,target=/home/jovyan/work jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

Both work just like the the first command, however the `work` folder is dissapearing from the hierarchy on the web interface. When trying to create it, it states that the folder allready exists, which I confirmed by opening a terminal and listing all folders at the current path with `ls`, where it showed up.

Mounting a different path creates a new folder with the same result: The folder is created but doesnt show up in the hierarchy. Mounting `/home/jovyan` makes the container exit upon starting it.

Is this the expected behaviour and am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it a problem with permissions?

The image docs in section [Docker Options](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html#docker-options) states that:

> -v /some/host/folder/for/work:/home/jovyan/work - Mounts a host machine directory as folder in the container. Useful when you want to
>   preserve notebooks and other work even after the container is
>   destroyed. **You must grant the within-container notebook user or
>   group (NB_UID or NB_GID) write access to the host directory (e.g.,
>   sudo chown 1000 /some/host/folder/for/work).**